# Java :How to replace any space (not whitespace), just space, which is not followed by another space with no space

Tags: java, regex

```
example :"4054a4:e8 c8 f0 ff ff   callq  404571 <junkfunction+0x552>"
o/p :"  4054a4:e8c8f0ffff  callq  404571<junkfunction+0x552>"
```

I tried using

```
string.replaceall("[ (? )]", "")
```

But it also takes out the space between callq and 404571.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `(?<![ ])[ ](?![ ])` is all you need.

Comment: From your output, I'm assuming you just want a lone space to go away. Otherwise, is there a reason to shorten up a variable amount of spaces (greater than 1) by one space?

Comment: Trying to extract the opcodes in asm files. I have all the opcodes stored in a hashmap,but finding out whether a line has a valid op code in it is difficult. From what I observed in almost all lines I can split the line on a space and use the word just before the last space to check it against a hash map containing all valid opcodes. The only impediment were lines like the ones in the question. I know this approach decreases the accuracy but I'm willing to let go of a little bit of accuracy since I'm using it for heuristics.
I'd love to hear and implement if there exists a better idea :)

Comment: Kind of looks like dissasembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you can use :

```
yourstring.replaceAll(" (?! )", "");
```

Comment: This will match "<space>`<space>`<not-space>".

Comment: @sln: I know, but it is what the OP asked: "a space not followed by another space"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following expression:

```
    (?=\S)
// ^
// There is a space here
```

This will match any space character as long as it is followed by something which is not a space `\S`.

Or if you prefer just regular spaces then:

```
(?! )
```

In Java:

```
String input = "4054a4:e8 c8 f0 ff ff   callq  404571 <junkfunction+0x552>";
String result = input.replace(" (?! )", "");
```

Comment: Hi @Sniffer: I used this code however it is returning the string as it is
"String before = "4054a4: e8 c8 f0 ff ff        callq  404571 <junkfunction+0x552>";
  String after = before.trim();
  System.out.println(after);
  after = after.replace(" (?! )", "");"
and a sysout after that but it gives the input string as the output.

Comment: @Ashwin Use `replaceAll()` instead, but the expression is working correctly.

Comment: Worked. I should have seen that. Will accept as soon this as the answer as soon as I can. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will match "<space>`<space>`<not-space>".

Comment: @sln Correct, but the OP didn't say otherwise. He wants to match space not followed by space.

Comment: Different to expected output but no less correct for OP's apparent needs.

Comment: +1 Ok, I see now. I posted a question to the OP because I think he missed the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
string.replaceall("(?<! ) (?! )", "")
```

Removes a space only if it has no other spaces either side. Leaves series of 2 or more space untouched as in your example.

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37bu8) - produces your exact output string

```
in:  4054a4:e8 c8 f0 ff ff   callq  404571 <junkfunction+0x552>
out: 4054a4:e8c8f0ffff   callq  404571<junkfunction+0x552>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done dumb:

```
string = string.replaceAll("( +) ", "$1");
```

Removes of any sequence of at least two spaces with one less.

Depends on boundary cases (spaces at end of string).